# gradients return None when trying to apply gradients to 2 keras models

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to combine a cnn and a transformers and apply the gradients to both models.

I create my CNN model:

> ```
> cnn_model = models.Sequential([
> layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3,
>                   strides=1, padding="causal",
>                   activation="relu",
>                   input_shape=[None, 1024]),
> layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1),
> layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3,
>                   strides=1, padding="causal",
>                   activation="relu"),
> layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1),
> layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3,
>                   strides=1, padding="causal",
>                   activation="relu"),
> layers.BatchNormalization(), ]) 
> cnn_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer)
>
> transformer = Transformer(num_layers, d_model2, num_heads, dff,
>                       input_vocab_size2, target_vocab_size2, 
>                       pe_input=input_vocab_size2, 
>                       pe_target=target_vocab_size2,
>                       rate=dropout_rate)
> ```

My optimizers and loss function are:

> ```
> def loss_function(real, pred):
>     mask = tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.equal(real, 0))
>     loss_ = loss_object(real, pred)
>
>     mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=loss_.dtype)
>     loss_ *= mask
>
>     return tf.reduce_sum(loss_)/tf.reduce_sum(mask)
>
> loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True, reduction='none')
> optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.98, epsilon=1e-9)
> ```

In my training step, I have:

> ```
> with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
>     
>     cnn_prediction = cnn_model(inp, training=True)
>     
>     predictions, _ = transformer(cnn_prediction, tar_inp, 
>                              True, 
>                              enc_padding_mask, 
>                              combined_mask, 
>                              dec_padding_mask)
>     loss = loss_function(tar_real, predictions)
>
> gradients = tape.gradient(loss, transformer.trainable_variables)
> optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, transformer.trainable_variables))
>
> cnn_gradients = tape.gradient(loss, cnn_model.trainable_variables)
> optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(cnn_gradients, cnn_model.trainable_variables))
>
> train_loss(loss)
> train_accuracy(accuracy_function(tar_real, predictions))
> ```

but when I apply gradients for the cnn model, what I get for cnn_gradients is:

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

and the error

```
No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv1d_10/kernel:0', 'conv1d_10/bias:0', 'conv1d_11/kernel:0', 'conv1d_11/bias:0', 'conv1d_12/kernel:0', 'conv1d_12/bias:0', 'conv1d_13/kernel:0', 'conv1d_13/bias:0', 'conv1d_14/kernel:0', 'conv1d_14/bias:0', 'conv1d_15/kernel:0', 'conv1d_15/bias:0', 'conv1d_16/kernel:0', 'conv1d_16/bias:0', 'conv1d_17/kernel:0', 'conv1d_17/bias:0', 'conv1d_18/kernel:0', 'conv1d_18/bias:0', 'conv1d_19/kernel:0', 'conv1d_19/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_3/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_3/beta:0'].
```

Any ideas on how I can make this work ? What am I missing to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the [`tf.GradientTape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape):

> By default, **the resources held by a GradientTape are released as soon as GradientTape.gradient() method is called.** To compute multiple gradients over the same computation, create a persistent gradient tape. This allows multiple calls to the gradient() method as resources are released when the tape object is garbage collected.

You should either use two tapes, or set `persistent=True` when creating your tape object, or update all your gradients at the same time:

#### Using `persistent=True`

```
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    intermediate_result = model1(inp)
    y_pred = model2(intermediate_result)
    loss = loss_func(y_true, y_pred)
model1_gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model1.trainable_variables)
model2_gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model2.trainable_variables)
```

Be aware that setting `persistent=True` can have some impact on performance.

#### Using 2 tapes

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape1, tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
    intermediate_result = model1(inp)
    y_pred = model2(intermediate_result)
    loss = loss_func(y_true, y_pred)
model1_gradients = tape1.gradient(loss, model1.trainable_variables)
model2_gradients = tape2.gradient(loss, model2.trainable_variables)
```

#### Calculating the gradient in one pass:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    intermediate_result = model1(inp)
    y_pred = model2(intermediate_result)
    loss = loss_func(y_true, y_pred)
all_gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model1.trainable_variables + model2.trainable_variables)
# applying the gradient in one pass as well
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(all_gradients, model1.trainable_variables + model2.trainable_variables))
```

I would probably favor the last option, which looks the simplest to me.

Comment: Hi @Lescurei ... thanks for your reply. I tried the first and second approach which still gave me cnn_gradientes = [None, None, None ... None]

and the 3rd gave me the error: 'bool' object has no attribute 'variables'

Comment: There was a typo in my 3rd example. Still the first two approaches should work. Is your `Transformer` class a keras model?

Comment: Hi, yes it is. I created like: class Transformer(tf.keras.Model):